# Variable resolution across DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, contour

[image]

I am try to build a contour map from this DEM but I've noticed that the resolution varies across it resulting in orthogonal contours and 'choke points' where contours are sharply forced together. How might I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure the green areas are part of the DEM?

Comment: I can sympathize: doing a contour map for Albuquerque has the same problem. The only real solution would be to use non-equally spaced contours perhaps based on data quantiles (eg, 10% top elevation is one contour, next 10% is another, etc).

Comment: Yes, all the areas area part of the DEM.